# Laravel package login redirects to start page with 302 status code

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-8

**Goal**

Login a user in a Laravel package.

**Problem**

Pressing the login button redirects to the startpage and in the console i get a 302 status code. Thats the route of the login button: `<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>`. It is defined in `web.php` as follows: `Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login')`. The same happens when i try it in in the addressbar with: `127.0.0.1:8000/login`.

**Description**

It's my first try with laravel packaged development. Therefore I created a new Laravel app with Laravel 8. With `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` i created the authentication scaffolding and now tried to make it a laravel package. I followed [this instructions](https://laravelpackage.com/).
You can find the whole branch of the project [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/limplecms/-/tree/packagestructure).
Thanks in advance for your time.
Thats the stucture of the package until now:

[image]

**Routes**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers\Admin\PagesController;
use Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;

// Set language

Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect()->back();
});


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('limplecms::welcome');
});

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

Route::get('/home', [Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::resource(config('limplecms.admin_index_pages_url'), PagesController::class)->middleware('can:admin');
```

**DependencyProvider of the package**

```
<?php

namespace Leonp5\Limplecms;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;

class LimpleCmsProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/../config/config.php', 'limplecms');
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/../config/auth.php', 'limplecms');
    }

    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {

        $this->registerRoutes();

        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'limplecms');


        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {

            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__ . '/../dist' => public_path('limplecms'),
            ], 'assets');


            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__ . '/../config/config.php' => config_path('limplecms.php'),
            ], 'config');

            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__ . '/../resources/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/limplecms'),
            ], 'views');
        }

        $gate->define("admin", function ($user) {
            return $user->hasRole("admin");
        });

        $gate->define("editor", function ($user) {
            return $user->hasRole("editor");
        });
    }

    protected function registerRoutes()
    {
        Route::group($this->routeConfiguration(), function () {
            $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php');
        });
    }

    protected function routeConfiguration()
    {
        return [
            // 'prefix' => config('limplecms.prefix'),
            'middleware' => config('limplecms.middleware'),
        ];
    }
}
```

**LoginController**
(The login/logout method is defined in the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` which comes from Laravel and i didn't change anything there)

```
<?php

namespace Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    // commenting out this line and add a specific redirectTo function for a custom redirect

    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    // needs to bring in Auth Facade

    /**
     * 
     * @return mixed 
     * @throws BindingResolutionException 
     */
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->hasRole("admin")) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('pages.index');
        } else {
            $this->redirectTo = route("home");
        }

        return $this->redirectTo;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        $login = request()->input('identity');

        $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
        request()->merge([$field => $login]);

        return $field;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = [
            'identity.required' => 'Email or username cannot be empty',
            'password.required' => 'Password cannot be empty',
        ];

        $request->validate([
            'identity' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ], $messages);
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace Leonp5\Limplecms\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('limplecms::home');
    }
}
```

**auth.php** (Config)
(Copied the standard file and only changed this line)

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Leonp5\Limplecms\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'admin_index_pages_url' => '/admin/pages',

    'prefix' => 'cms',
    'middleware' => ['web'],
];
```

**The standard scaffolding welcome blade**
(Don't think, that the problem is here because entering the `127.0.0.1:8000/login` in the browser addressbar also redirects. But who knows...)

```
<div class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center sm:pt-0">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="hidden fixed top-0 right-0 px-6 py-4 sm:block">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </div>
            @endif
```

Comment: So what is "the login button"? What URL does it go to? What method gets run?

Comment: HTTP 302 status code means the redirection, that is not an error code. Look for all status codes here: https://httpstatuses.com/

Comment: I define route to the login function in LoginController, but "login" function is not exist in your LoginController. And also logout function don't exists

Comment: Thanks for your comments @AdamP. @miken32 :) I tried to clarify the question.
I guess, "the login button" is not the problem because the same behaviour occurs, when i simply try to call the page via `127.0.0.1:8000/login`. The login and logout functions are defined in the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` which is inside of `LoginController`. I thought it works because before Laravel 8 in a normal app (not package) you could call it this way: `Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adam P. comment i tried to define the route in the `LoginController` for showing the login form and that works. So inside the `LoginController` i added this method:

```
 public function show()
    {
        return view('limplecms::auth.login');
    }
```

And inside of `web.php`, where the routes get defined i changed
`Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');`
to
`Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'show'])->name('login');`